# SELECT into a foreach return previous values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a ***document classification table*** based on user role, for example:

| workforce_class_worker_doc_id | workforce_class_worker_doc_role_id | workforce_class_worker_doc_description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Drive license |
| 2 | 1 | Contract |

A ***worker table***

| workforce_worker_id | workforce_worker_name | workforce_role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 1 |

And a ***workforce_docs*** where are uploaded pdf

| workforce_doc_id | workforce_doc_worker_id | workforce_doc_class_id | workforce_doc_valid_from | workforce_doc_valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |

I'm trying to get with foreach document classification and with a new select get document  document validity

```
<table class="table table-sm my-2">
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($data as $row) {
            $workforce_class_worker_doc_id = $row['workforce_class_worker_doc_id'];
            $workforce_class_worker_doc_description = $row['workforce_class_worker_doc_description'];

            $stmt = $conn->prepare(' SELECT workforce_doc_class_id, workforce_doc_valid_from, workforce_doc_valid_to
                                       FROM workforce_docs
                                      WHERE workforce_doc_class_id = ?
                                        AND workforce_doc_worker_id = ? ');
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $workforce_class_worker_doc_id, $workforce_worker_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result( $workforce_doc_class_id, $workforce_doc_valid_from, $workforce_doc_valid_to ); 
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
        ?>

            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $workforce_class_worker_doc_description; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $workforce_doc_valid_from; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $workforce_doc_valid_to; ?></th>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">+ Update Document</button></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm experiencing a trouble with foreach, i expect result like this:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Drive License | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| Contract |  |  |

But my result is

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Drive License | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| Contract | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |

seem get previous variables, need must be blank because i not have record on doc table

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Comment: 10.4.18-MariaDB

Comment: Ok I see, But I didn't see any sample data from `workforce_docs` table but you are using in your code.

Could you explain about that? thanks.

Comment: Ok! I have updated, is last table before script

Comment: so what if the SQL statement is executed in DB clients like MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @Raptor I run this on AMP environment with PHP script

Comment: Why don't you simply do a left join in your sql code, rather than simulating a join through nested loops in php?

Comment: @HidDencum I mean the result is different in DB clients or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

This doesn't have result on the second run, therefore

```
$stmt->bind_result( $workforce_doc_class_id, $workforce_doc_valid_from, $workforce_doc_valid_to );
```

Is not executed. This would make `$workforce_doc_class_id, $workforce_doc_valid_from, $workforce_doc_valid_to` to have previous value.

I would suggest to reset value prior to that line:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $workforce_doc_class_id = '';
    $workforce_doc_valid_from = '';
    $workforce_doc_valid_to = '';
    ...
    //rest of the code
```

Comment: thank you for your time, more suitable your advice for my case. HID

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to make a LEFT JOIN before that, query is simply and more faster

```
// in your foreach query your query add
LEFT JOIN workforce_docs ON workforce_doc_class_id = workforce_class_worker_doc_id
```

and change your foreach to:

```
 foreach ($data as $row) {
     $workforce_class_worker_doc_id = $row['workforce_class_worker_doc_id'];
     $workforce_class_worker_doc_description = $row['workforce_class_worker_doc_description'];
     $workforce_doc_valid_from = $row['workforce_doc_valid_from'];
     $workforce_doc_valid_to = $row['workforce_doc_valid_to'];
     ... rest of the code ...
```